# Goにオートローダーってありますか？

Tags: go

import タグに毎回記述するので、若干運用が大変な気がします。
goimports -w をするのが作法なんでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

> goimports -w をするのが作法なんでしょうか？

そういった文化のようです。
正確に言うと、コードの編集後には `gofmt` で整形しておくのが作法であり、さらに `import`の記述も自動化したいという人が、`gofmt`の代りに`goimports`を使っているという形です。

---

例えば`vim`の golang用プラグイン`vim-go` はファイルの保存時に `gofmt` を自動で実行するのがデフォルト動作ですが、下記のように、`goimports` を使う設定も紹介されています。

> Enable goimports to automatically insert import paths instead of gofmt:
>   `let g:go_fmt_command = "goimports"`

https://github.com/fatih/vim-go

Comment: ありがとうございます。
大変参考になりました。